# SAS - title of the graph inside the object of the graph

Tags: sas

My problem is following - I am creating a graph but the title appears as a separate item in the output. I would like to incorporate it into the object of graph (to be able to export it as a picture). The code I am using is following:

```
/*graf puvodni hodnoty + predicted values*/
symbol1 interpol=join height=10pt VALUE=NONE LINE=1 WIDTH=2 CV= _STYLE_;
symbol2 interpol=join height=10pt VALUE=NONE LINE=1 WIDTH=2 CV= _STYLE_;
symbol3 interpol=join height=10pt VALUE=NONE LINE=1 WIDTH=2 CV= _STYLE_;
symbol4 interpol=join height=10pt VALUE=NONE LINE=1 WIDTH=2 CV= _STYLE_;
Legend1 label=(color=black height=1 "Variables:")
value=(color=black height=1 "LAPSE RATE - data" "LAPSE RATE - model with i.r." "LAPSE RATE - model w/o i.r." "Y5_swap_rate")
across=1 down=3;
axis1 label=('%, annualized');
axis2 label=('date');
title "Comparison of models";
proc gplot data= MYDATA.STORNO_KZP_1_REG;
    plot (ann_Lr ann_Lr_fitted ann_Lr_fitted_2 Y5_swap_rate)*datum/ overlay skipmiss
    VAXIS=AXIS1 
    HAXIS=AXIS2 
    LEGEND=LEGEND1;
run;
```

And the outcome looks in this way (with the red arrow showing where I would expect the title to appear):

[image]

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm maybe trying title2, or check the examples on this page, the code is available as well: http://support.sas.com/sassamples/graphgallery/PROC_GPLOT.html

Comment: thx, but title2 just adds another title under the current one, i.e. both of them are two separate items not included in the graph.

Comment: Sry I'd like to be of more help but I don't have SAS/Graph :(  Have you checked the examples mentionned above though?

Comment: no worry. Yeah, i have checked it. The case is that at all illustrative examples (either in your link or on other websites) the title is being created as a part of graph, in my case it is just separate item. Despite the fact that the command is the same for both cases: title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you have the `gtitle` option of `ods html` turned off.

Try running this sample, first with the `nogtitle` only and second with the `gtitle` line uncommented.  `gtitle` tells SAS to put the title into the image itself rather than making it a text fill.  `gtitle` is usually on by default, at least by 9.3, but perhaps not in an older version (or your site has changed it on purpose).

```
goptions reset=all cback=white border htext=10pt htitle=12pt;                                                                           
ods html nogtitle; 
*ods html gtitle;
/* Create data to plot */                                                                                                               
data samples;                                                                                                                           
   input year mn n k;                                                                                                                   
   datalines;                                                                                                                           
2008  0.19  45  10.6                                                                                                                    
2009  0.25  54  9.2                                                                                                                     
2010  0.52  35  11.0                                                                                                                    
2011  0.15  48  7.2                                                                                                                     
2012  0.38  29  8.1                                                                                                                     
;                                                                                                                                       
run;                                                                                                                                    

/* Create a format to display the data values with percent signs */                                                                     
proc format;                                                                                                                            
   picture pctfmt low - high = '009.9%';                                                                                                
run;                                                                                                                                    

/* Define the title */                                                                                                                  
title1 "Sample Analysis";                                                                                                               

/* The FOOTNOTE statement creates a legend */                                                                                           
footnote1 height=9pt 'N=Nitrogen    K=Potassium    Mn=Manganese';                                                                       

/* Create the AXIS definitions that draw a thick border around the */                                                                   
/* plot area and display multiple scales on the vertical axes      */                                                                   
axis1 order=(2008 to 2012 by 1)                                                                                                         
      value=(font='Arial/bold' height=11pt)                                                                                             
      offset=(4,4)                                                                                                                      
      width=2                                                                                                                           
      label=none                                                                                                                        
      major=none                                                                                                                        
      minor=none;                                                                                                                       
axis2 order=(0 to .6 by .2, 3, 6 to 12 by 2, 13, 15 to 60 by 15)                                                                        
      label=(angle=90 'Concentration')                                                                                                  
      value=(tick=5 ' ' tick=10 ' ')                                                                                                    
      offset=(2,2);                                                                                                                     
axis3 order=(0 to .6 by .2, 3, 6 to 12 by 2, 13, 15 to 60 by 15)                                                                        
      label=none                                                                                                                        
      value=(tick=5 ' ' tick=10 ' ')                                                                                                    
      offset=(2,2);                                                                                                                     

/* Define the symbol characteristics */                                                                                                 

/* SYMBOL1-SYMBOL3 draw a dot at each point */                                                                                          
/* and connect the points with a line.    */                                                                                            
symbol1 interpol=join width=2 color=vligb  value=dot height=6;                                                                          
symbol2 interpol=join width=2 color=salmon value=dot height=6;                                                                          
symbol3 interpol=join width=2 color=vibg   value=dot height=6;                                                                           

/* SYMBOL4-SYMBOL6 are used with the PLOT2 statement and display the */                                                                 
/* character symbol of the corresponding element for each point  */                                                                     
symbol4 interpol=none value='Mn' font='Arial/bold' color=black height=12pt;                                                             
symbol5 interpol=none value='K'  font='Arial/bold' color=black height=12pt;                                                             
symbol6 interpol=none value='N'  font='Arial/bold' color=black height=12pt;                                                             


/* Generate the graph */                                                                                                                
proc gplot data=samples;

   plot (mn k n)*year / overlay haxis=axis1 vaxis=axis2                                                                               
                        vref=3 13 cframe=grayee;                                                                                      
   plot2 (mn k n)*year / overlay vaxis=axis3;                                                                                         
   format mn k n pctfmt.;                                                                                                               
run;                                                                                                                                    
quit;
```

The same option appears on most other ods destinations.